# vb.net application does not run on windows xp machine

Tags: vb.net

I have an application made using Visual studio 2008 and it uses a Microsoft access 2007 file as back end database(file). it works well on my laptop running windows 7 64 bit. but I get an error when I  install and try to run it on my PC running windowsxp and Office2000. the error is" Microsoft oledb12.0 not registered on your machine".

how can i run the application on my PC ?

Comment: You must build it with `x86` cpu

Comment: Have you installed this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: if you are taking 'target cpu' in compile properties, then yes i have already selected x86..

Answer (score 0):

> "Microsoft oledb12.0 not registered on your machine"
>
> how can i run the application on my PC ?

Since you used **MS Access 2007** DB as back end then you should install at least **MS Office 2007** or later on your PC ..